# When tabbing only open dropdown when hitting enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few dropdowns in a list. Currently, when I hover over the dropdowns they open just fine. However, when tabbing through the website when I tab through each list item the dropdown opens. I would like to only open the dropdown when hitting enter then continue to tab through the menu afterwards while keeping the hover functionality the same.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown tabindex="2">
            <a class="menu-anchor" href="javascript:;" tabindex="-1">Program Areas</a> 
            <i class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display: none;"></i>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown tabindex="2">
            <a class="menu-anchor" href="javascript:;" tabindex="-1">Program Areas</a> 
            <i class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display: none;"></i>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown tabindex="2">
            <a class="menu-anchor" href="javascript:;" tabindex="-1">Program Areas</a> 
            <i class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display: none;"></i>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: There's no actual drop-downs in the example code, which library creates the drop-downs?

Comment: What is the magic code that makes them open/close?

Comment: @epascarello see updated code, let me know if this helps

Comment: That is going to require some JavaScript. You can change it to `.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu,
    .dropdown:focus > .dropdown-menu,
    .dropdown > .dropdown-menu:focus` and it would open auto without enter.